# Extract a substring using lex regular expressions

Tags: regex, lex

Is it possible to extract a substring with `lex` regular expressions, like it can be done with `sed`?

For example

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]*\([a-z]*\)[0-9]*/\1/'
```

will extract `foo` from `34234foo777` or `bar` from `123bar456`

Is it possible to do that with lex like this:

```cpp
[0-9]*\([a-z]*\)[0-9]*     printf("alphabetical substring is %s\n", /*what?? \1 ??*/);
```

without parsing `yytext` by plain C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution using Yacc, considering that `[0-9] is numeric and [a-z]` is alpha

so your grammar is :

```
stmt : NUMERIC ALPHA NUMERIC    printf("alphabetical substring is %s\n", $2)
     ;
```

ALPHA and NUMERIC  given by the lex